# Estimate exponential equation from graph

Tags: exponential-function, estimation

Output `y` of a system is a non increasing function of an input `x`
Based on my studies I have found that it can be estimated as below 
$$
y = be^{ax}+c
$$
From measurement I have five values of `y` for `x` that are not equally spaced. I.e I have values of `y` for `x= 5,10,20,40,50`.
Values of `y` are exponentially decreasing and hence should fit the generic equation above.

The task at hand is to find values of `a`,`b` and `c` from these five measurement data. I understand that I have enough points of data for calculating three unknowns. I want to know a iterative/generic logic to come up with estimations of these unknowns, since I have to do this for hundreds of measurements.

PS:
Some points already known to me

- `c` can be estimated by looking for asymptotes
- `a` is negative as my function is exponentially decreasing with `x`

I am new to this community, Please consider that while you answer/comment

Comment: have you tried the Least Squares method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c$ is known then we have points of the form
$$(x_i,be^{ax_i})$$
after shifting the data by $(0,-c)$. This relation can be rewritten as
$$y=be^{ax}\implies\ln{(y)}=ax+\ln{(b)}$$
So the variables $\ln{(y)}$ and $x$ are linearly related. The [Least Squares Regression](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/least-squares-regression.html) line can then be found for $\ln{(y)}$ and $x$ giving a relation of the form
$$\ln{(y)}=mx+c=ax+\ln{(b)}$$
Hence the value of $a$ is given by the gradient $m$ of the Least Squares Regression line between $\ln{(y)}$ and $x$. Also, the value of $b$ is given by $e^c$ where $c$ is the $y$-axis intercept of the Least Squares Regression line between $\ln{(y)}$ and $x$.

Comment: I was curious on how to start if C is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful with this type of problems. In the least square sense, what you want is to minimize
$$SSQ(a,b,c)=\sum_{i=1}^n(b\,e^{a\,x_i}+c-y_i)^2$$ which is nonlinear because of $a$ and then you need reasonable estimates to start the nonlinear regression.

If $c$ is known, the problem is quite simple because you can, in a **first** step, linearize the model as
$$\log(y-c)=\log(b)+a x=\beta + ax$$ as Peter Foreman did explain. Then, a standard linear regression gives **estimates** of parameters $(a,b)$. However, you must not stop at this point because what has been measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337601/fit-exponential-with-constant/1338588#1338588) could be of interest for you.