# How do you calculate the horizontal asymptote for a declining exponential?

Tags: exponential-function, regression

I am recovering from an injury and I go for a run each morning. The distance that I run does not change but the time is getting shorter each time, i.e. I am improving. I am recording my times and would like to fit an exponential of the form $y(x)=A+Be^{Cx}$ to the data such that I can predict my future minimum time for that journey when I am at full fitness. i.e. I want to know the $A$ value. $y=Time(min)$ and $x=Days$.

Here is my data: $(Day,Time)={(0,78),(1,76),(2,76),(3,70),(4,68),(5,69),(6,66),(7,66),(8,65),(9,66),(10,64),(11,64),(12,63)}$

When I plot these data there does seem to be an exponential improvement forming. But I haven't done it long enough yet to reach my plateauing time.

My calculator has an exponential function but it assumes an $A=0$, which cannot be true. How do I estimate or calculate my $A$ value?

Answer (score 2):

There are many places on this site where you can see the problem of the fit of exponential functions like
$$y=a+b\, e^{cx}$$ Just have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163618/exponential-curve-fit).

Using that, you should find (using your data)
$$y=61.7695 +17.0408 e^{-0.196822 x}$$ corresponding to $R^2=0.999742$.

The key problem is that you need "reasonable" estimates. You could have obtained them in a first step using $a\approx 60$ and then consider
$$y-60=b \,e^{cx} \implies \log(y-60)=\log(b)+cx\implies z=d+ cx$$

Comment: Thanks Claude Leibovici. But that result does not make any sense. A normal person could run that distance in say 30 to 40 minutes. Your solution suggests that the minimum time that I could obtain would be 62 minutes. I ran it in 63 minutes this morning and I have only started this training regime. I can't believe that I will only improve by one more minute.

Comment: @Derek. I considered the general problem. Now, if you have constraints, the problem can be slightly different.

Comment: @Derek. My *"result does not make any sense"* but you asked for the fit of  such a model. What it could mean is that, for a few days, you would not improve much and, at a time, change your performances. By the way, a linear regression is almost as good. I wish you a good and prompt recovery.

Comment: @Derek. Seriously, I would like you continue recording your performances for a while. Update the data. I would like to see how these could be analyzed. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again Claude Leibovici. I will update the data later. I agree that a linear regression works reasonably well at this early stage. But based on the nature of the data it can't continue as a linear function as it is impossible for me to run that distance in zero time. There has to be a horizontal asymptote somewhere. But I guess it's just too early in the analysis to estimate that. I'll supplement the data later. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How can you guess a "reasonable" initial value for $a$ value if you don't have any so called "domain specific information" on the data?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici To be sure - your suggestion is to use $(60, \exp\{\widehat{\log b}\}, \hat{c})$ as initial values for the non-linear regression, right? If so, are there any general results on what will happen if we start from some "ridiculous" point like $(-10000, \exp\{\widehat{\log b}\}\ \hat{c})$ for this specific model?